# Get right-hand side of equation

Tags: function, equation, maxima

I am calling the function `mnewton(0=expr, alpha, %pi/4)` to get the root of a rather complex equation `expr`.

```
%(i1)   mnewton(0=expr, alpha, %pi/4)
%(o1)   [alpha=0.678193754078621]
```

I need to apply another function to this result (e.g. `sin`) and then want to plot it. Just linking the functions does not work:

```
%(i2)   sin(mnewton(0=expr, alpha, %pi/4)[1])
%(o2)   sin(alpha=0.678193754078621)
```

This is because the expression `alpha=0.678193754078621` is not a number. **How do I convert `alpha=0.678193754078621` to just `0.678193754078621`?**

I can't just copy the numerical value and add it manually as I want to plot this and my `expr` will have a different root for each y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function **`rhs(expr)`** does exactly that.

Check [the manual](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_20.html#rhs) for more information on this.